# Tag search in HTML using js in ant

Tags: ant

I am using the below mentioned code to get the content of a specific tag, but when I am trying to execute it I am getting some extra data along with it, I don't understand why is it happening. Lets say if I search for title tag then I am getting `" [echo] Title : <title>Unit Test Results</title>,Unit Test Results"` this as result, but the problem is title only contains `"<title>Unit Test Results</title>"` why this extra `",Unit Test Results"` thing is coming.

```
<project name="extractElement" default="test">
<!--Extract element from html file-->
<scriptdef name="findelement" language="javascript">
     <attribute name="tag" />
     <attribute name="file" />
     <attribute name="property" />
     <![CDATA[
       var tag = attributes.get("tag");
       var file = attributes.get("file");
       var regex = "<" + tag + "[^>]*>(.*?)</" + tag + ">";
       var patt = new RegExp(regex,"g");
       project.setProperty(attributes.get("property"), patt.exec(file));
     ]]>
</scriptdef>

<!--Only available target...-->
<target name="test">
    <loadfile srcFile="E:\backup\latest report\Report-20160523_2036.html" property="html.file"/>
    <findelement tag="title" file="${html.file}" property="element"/>
    <echo message="Title : ${element}"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `RegExp.exec()` is an array. From [the Mozilla documentation on RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then
>   one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the
>   text that was captured.

If you add the following code to your JavaScript...

```js
var patt = new RegExp(regex,"g");
var execResult = patt.exec(file);
print("execResult: " + execResult);
print("execResult.length: " + execResult.length);
print("execResult[0]: " + execResult[0]);
print("execResult[1]: " + execResult[1]);
```

...you'll get the following output...

```
[findelement] execResult: <title>Unit Test Results</title>,Unit Test Results
[findelement] execResult.length: 2
[findelement] execResult[0]: <title>Unit Test Results</title>
[findelement] execResult[1]: Unit Test Results
```